# Cordova push notification using Azure notification-hub

Tags: android, cordova, azure, push-notification, notifications

I'm developing 2 mobile apps using apache cordova and the backend as Azure.
There are 2 mobile application as App1 and App2. What I want is that when the App1 user does some activity and  report it to the App2 user, the App2 user should get a push notification and should be able to authorize that activity.

What I have done up to now is, I have created a notification hub in the Azure portal and implemented the cordova push notification plugin into my mobile app.

How to proceed with the next steps?